# Is it true? $F(y^3/3)+G(y^3/3)=8y^3 \iff F(x)+G(x)=24x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I got: $u(x,y)=F(y^3/3-x)+G(y^3/3+x)$ and the initial conditions :
$$\begin{cases}
u(0,y)=8y^3\\
u_x(0,y)=6
\end{cases} \iff 
\begin{cases} F(y^3/3)+G(y^3/3)=8y^3\\ -F'(y^3/3)+G'(y^3/3)=6
\end{cases}$$
I tried to continue as such:
$$F(y^3/3)+G(y^3/3)=8y^3 \iff F(x)+G(x)=24x$$
$$-F'(y^3/3)+G'(y^3/3)=6\iff-F'(x)+G'(x)=6$$
But I feel like it's wrong. Hope u guys point out for me!

keep moving, it goes like: $$F'(x)+G'(x)=24$$ then $$\begin{cases} F'(x)=9\\ G'(x)=15\end{cases}$$

Comment: Why does it feel wrong to you? It looks good to me!

Comment: I've checked again, It goes correct, thank u!